# Torus as example of supermanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Where can I find examples of supermanifold? In particular "supertorus". I am interested in the complex differential forms expressed on such geometries, and moreover I would like to know if hodge numbers for complex supermanifolds can be computed. Some reference would be of a great help